# Setting <audio> element to 50% volume when <video> is playing

Tags: jquery, html, audio, video, volume

Hey everyone i hope you can answer this :)

Basically i have a few html 5 videos in my index.html with background audio auto playing.

What i want to happen is reduced the background audio to 50% when the video tag is playing. Would be good if i could use a class to target all video elements if possible :) if the user exits the video it turns the volume back to 100%

Im currently using jQuery for my project so a solution in jQuery would be great!

Currently i think it would be along the lines of this....

```
// to reduce volume to 50%. im not sure what the code would be to reduce volume ? maybe 0.5 or something ?

    $("video").click(function(){
        $(audio).mute();
    });

// turn volume back to 100% once exit button is clicked

    $(".exit").click(function(){

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `audio.volume = 0.5` should provide the desired result (reduce volume to 50%) and `audio.volume = 1.0` to set the volume back to 100%. See [MDN Docs](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=JavaScript&docset_name=JavaScript&path=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume.html&platform=javascript&repo=Main&source=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume) for more details.

See snippet below (click the buttons and look at the volume controls bar):

```js
var $audio = $('#audio-test').get(0);

$('#set-volume-50').click(function(){
  $audio.volume = 0.5;
});

$('#set-volume-100').click(function(){
  $audio.volume = 1.0;
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio-test" controls="controls">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
  <source src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
  <button id="set-volume-50">Set volume to 50%</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <button id="set-volume-100">Set volume to 100%</button>
```

Comment: thanks :) ill give this a whirl and see if i can make it work!

Comment: @Mayo I've added a snippet to my answer